# Complement of Graph Coloring Problem

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a graph $G$ and I find complement of it Graph $G'$ and now do Graph Coloring on Graph $G'$. Since $G'$ is complement , Which means no two adjacent nodes of $G'$ will be colored same following the property of graph coloring.

I understand that nodes which are colored **same** in $G'$ are *adjacent in G*. This can be proved easily. But -

**Claim 1:**  Can I say the nodes which are **colored differently** in $G'$ will not have any edge in original graph $G$ ?

If yes , what's the proof?

**Note: It is assumed that minimum number of colors are used for coloring.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you don’t impose some assumption like the coloring being minimal or something.

Color the graph $\bullet \;\;\bullet$ with two different colors. The complement is $\bullet - \bullet$, which has an edge, although the nodes had different colors.

Even when imposing minimality the claim remains false. Consider a $C_4$, whose complement is two disjoint copies of an edge. The latter is 2-colorable and we can choose a coloring in such a way that two adjacent vertices in $C_4$ would inherit the same color. See the attached image (uncropped due to technical difficulties)
[image: counterexample]

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention about this assumption. I have edited the question. I am not coloring original graph. I am just coloring the complement and want to reach conclusions from complement

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, can you please have a look at my extended question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143071/finding-largest-mesh-network-in-a-graph